# What is wrong with this string assignment?

Tags: c++, string

```
string s="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
char f[]=" " (s.substr(s.length()-10,9)).c_str() " ";
```

I want to get the last 9 characters of s and add " " to the beginning and the end of the substring, and store it as a char[]. I don't understand why this doesn't work even though char f[]=" " "a" " " does.

Is (s.substr(s.length()-10,9)).c_str() not a string literal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, consider whether you should be using cstrings. In C++, generally, use string.

However, if you want to use cstrings, the concatenation of `"abc" "123"` -> `"abc123"` is a preprocessor operation and so cannot be used with string::c_str(). Instead, the easiest way is to construct a new string and take the .c_str() of that:

```
string s="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
char f[]= (string(" ") + s.substr(s.length()-10,9) + " ").c_str();
```

(EDIT: You know what, on second thought, that's a really bad idea. The cstring should be deallocated after the end of this statement, so using f can cause a segfault. Just don't use cstrings unless you're prepared to mess with strcpy and all that ugly stuff. Seriously.)

If you want to use strings instead, consider something like the following:

```
#include <sstream>
...
string s="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
stringstream tmp;
tmp << " " << s.substr(s.length()-10,9) << " ";
string f = tmp.str();
```

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not a string literal. String literals always have the form `"<content>"` or expand to that (macros, like `__FILE__` for example).

Just use another `std::string` instead of `char[]`.

```
std::string f = " " + s.substr(s.size()-10, 9) + " ";
```

Comment: `std::ostringstream s; s << " " << s.substr(...) << " "; std::string f = s.str();`

Comment: Doesn't `__LINE__` expand to an integer literal?

Answer (score 1):

@Xeo tells you how to solve your problem. Here's some complimentary background on how string literals are handled in the compilation process.

From section A.12 Preprocessing of [The C Programming language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628):

> Escape sequences in character constants and string literals (Pars. A.2.5.2, A.2.6) are
>   replaced by their equivalents; then adjacent string literals are concatenated.

It's the Preprocessor, not the compiler, who's responsible for the concatenation. (You asked for a C++ answer. I expect that C++ treats string literals the same way as C). The preprocessor has only a limited knowledge of the C/C++ language; the `(s.substr(s.length()-10,9)).c_str()` part is not evaluated at the preprocessor stage.